# quantile in scipy library

Tags: python, quantiles

I am confused what is quantile in [scipy.stats.norm.pdf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) function.
Definition of [quantile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) says that k-th of q-quantile is essentially value which divides population into k/q and (q-k)/q parts. But if I call

```
scipy.stats.norm.pdf([0,1,2,3,4], 2, 9)
```

then I will get vector `v` with 5 numbers. What `v[i]' mean in this case? probability of normal RV been equal`i`?
Could you clarify it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the normal pdf, with parameters $\mu=2$ and $\sigma=9$, evaluated  at the points 0,1,2,3,4. It cannot be interpreted as a probability as is. Are you interested in probabilities or quantiles?

If you want quantiles, try

```
scipy.stats.norm.ppf( [.05,.5, .95], 2, 9)
```

will give you the quantiles at the points 0.05, .5 and .95. For example, the solution to $P( N_{2,9} < q ) = 0.05$ is scipy.stats.norm.ppf(.05, 2,9).